# What is the correct way to use RelativeSource in the outer tag?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, maui

I want to avoid repeating `Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:MainViewModel}}` in the following.

```
<SwipeView ...   xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Todo.ViewModel">
    <SwipeView.LeftItems>
        <SwipeItems>
            <SwipeItem Text="Delete" 
                Command="{Binding DeleteCommand,Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:MainViewModel}}}" />
        </SwipeItems>
    </SwipeView.LeftItems>
    <Grid Padding="0,5">
        <Frame >
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                Command="{Binding TapCommand,Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:MainViewModel}}}"/>
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
</SwipeView>
```

I do the following but it does not work as expected.

```
<SwipeView ... xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Todo.ViewModel"
    BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:MainViewModel}}}"
        >
    <SwipeView.LeftItems>
        <SwipeItems>
            <SwipeItem Text="Delete"  Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
        </SwipeItems>
    </SwipeView.LeftItems>
    <Grid Padding="0,5">
        <Frame >
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer  Command="{Binding TapCommand}" />
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
</SwipeView>
```

### Repo

Use the following repo to avoid getting inconsistent results (among us) and to make sure we are talking in the same scope.

https://github.com/pstricks-fans/Todo

Here are the relevant parts:

**MySwipeView:**

```cs
public partial class MySwipeView : SwipeView
{
    public MySwipeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

```xml
<SwipeView ...
    x:Class="Todo.CustomControls.MySwipeView"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Todo.ViewModel"
    >
    <SwipeView.LeftItems>
        <SwipeItems>
            <SwipeItem 
                Text="Delete" 
                Command="{Binding DeleteCommand,Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:MainViewModel}}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
        </SwipeItems>
    </SwipeView.LeftItems>
    <Grid Padding="0,5">
        <Frame >
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                Command="{Binding TapCommand,Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:MainViewModel}}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <Label Text="{Binding .}" FontSize="24"/>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
</SwipeView>
```

**MainPage:**

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(MainViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }
}
```

```xml
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Todo.CustomControls"
             xmlns:vm="using:Todo.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel"
             >

    <Grid ... >


        <CollectionView ...  >
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <local:MySwipeView />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

**MainViewModel:**

```cs
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [RelayCommand]
    void Delete(string s){}

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task Tap(string s){}
}
```

Comment: Try `Binding ., Source=…`

Comment: Can you provide a link that shows using a RelativeSource that is a ViewModel? That was never possible in Xamarin.Forms; if that works in Maui, then I need more information about the situation.

Comment: Its ok, I found the concept discussed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings.  It automatically searches for an "ancestor's binding context" with that type. (Technically, uses `FindAncestorBindingContext` instead of `FindAncestor` Element.) Thinking it through now.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, SwipeView is being used inside an `ItemTemplate`. You MUST NOT change its BindingContext; that has to be the associated Item.

Therefore, your original goal is NOT POSSIBLE; we can simplify the "Source" expression, but we cannot eliminate it.

Simplest I know is:

```xml
Command="{Binding VM.DeleteCommand, Source={x:Reference thePage}}"
```

Explanation: On "thePage", finds property "VM", which contains a property "DeleteCommand". Make the following changes to `MainPage`.

```xml
<ContentPage
   ...
   x:Name="thePage"
   x:Class="MainPage">
```

```cs
class MainPage : ContentPage
{
  // You can change this name. Be sure to use same name in XAML above.
  public property MainViewModel VM { get; set; }

  public MainPage(MainViewModel vm)
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    // Put this line BEFORE set BindingContext. Used by XAML.
    VM = vm;
    BindingContext = vm;
  }
```

Comment: Good point. No, we have to pass VM down. I adapted this from a situation where the XAML was all in one file. Add `BindableProperty MainVMProperty` with associated property `MainViewModel MainVM` to SwipeView, and set that by `<local:MySwipeView MainVM="{Binding VM}" />`, then use `{Binding MainVM.DeleteCommand}`. I'm out of time; see if you can get that to work. May have to experiment with syntax.

Comment: That isn't a useful comment, unless you **add to question** a section that shows exactly the code you tried. Then explain what you did to debug it, to determine what about it did not work. Did it not compile? Not find the property? A breakpoint in the property is never hit? Are there any relevant messages in VS Output when you run?

Comment: Could you share your repo to make sure it works? I have done many combinatorial attempts based on your answer but the binding does not work (the same unexpected result as my attempt in the question).

Answer (score 0):

At first, the format of [binding to an ancestor in the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings#bind-to-an-ancestor) is something like `{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:PeopleViewModel}}, Path=DeleteEmployeeCommand}`

And then you can try to set the SwipeView's binding context in the construction method instead of the binding way you used.

I have done a sample to test, and the binding worked well:

The MySwipeView.cs :

```
    public partial class MySwipeView : SwipeView
    {
      public ICommand TestCommand { get; private set; }
      public MySwipeView()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
            TestCommand = new Command<string>(Test);
            //BindingContext = this;
            BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
      }
      void Test(string print)
      {
            Debug.WriteLine("============"+print);
      }

    }
```

The MySwipeView.xaml:

```
<SwipeView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiAppTest.MySwipeView"
             >
    <SwipeView.LeftItems>
        <SwipeItems>
            <SwipeItem
                Text="Delete"
                Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"
                CommandParameter="xxxxxxxxx"/>
        </SwipeItems>
    </SwipeView.LeftItems>
    <Grid Padding="0,5">
        <Frame >
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
                CommandParameter="xxxxxxxx"/>
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <Label Text="xxxxxxxx" FontSize="24"/>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
</SwipeView>
```

The MainPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp21"
             x:Class="MauiApp21.MainPage">

    <HorizontalStackLayout>
        <local:MySwipeView/>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

The MyViewModel.cs:

```
public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [RelayCommand]
        void Delete(string value) { Debug.WriteLine("===========Delete"); }
        [RelayCommand]
        void Tap(string value) { Debug.WriteLine("===============Tap"); }
    }
```

No matter the `BindingContext` is `this` or the `MyViewModel`, the command will run successfully.

Comment: Did `{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:MainViewModel}}, Path=DeleteCommand}` work? @TheRealMasochist

Comment: It seems the swipeview's bindingcontext bind failed. According to the example about the RelativeSource in the official document, it need a path. You can try something like `<SwipeView ... xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Todo.ViewModel"
    BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPage} } ,Path = BindingContext}". >`@TheRealMasochist

Comment: I am using my scenario in the first part in my question and I deleted the `,Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:MainViewModel}}`. It does **NOT** work.

Comment: `MySwipeView` is sandwiched in `CollectionView.ItemTemplate`. It is mandatory.